# have thrust vs have thrusted: Which is the more frequently used past tense and past participle of "thrust"?

Tags: past-tense, past-participles, irregular-verbs

*Thrust* or *thrusted*?

As in:

> I'm walking through the old neighborhood right now, and, yes, the idiots have thrust (thrusted?) in yet another stupid skyscraper.

Comment: *Some are born great, some achieve greatness, and some have greatness thrusted upon them???*

Comment: @PeterShor: Shakespeare lived, like, years ago.

Comment: [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thrust) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thrust) are clear about the answer, although you have to know the format of their dictionary entries.